# Visualizing convolution and deconvolution layers in mathematica

Tags: image-processing, animation, code-request, generative-art

I found this series of visualizations of NN layers working principle fascinating ([link](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic)):

[image]

Can you provide some tips how to build such animation in Mathematica?

Comment: Just say 'show me the code', the likelihood of getting an answer will be the same and you will save us the time spend on thinking about efficiency. :)

Comment: @Kuba, I've noticed that 'show me the code' releases more time for thinking about closing and downvoting ))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay lets do this:

first we'll build a ground structure. Some Variables to define our Rectangle sizes. 
Next a variable to store our frames and a [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) which constructs them. At last a [`ListAnimate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html).

```
topTileLength = 2;
bottomTileLength = 4;
frames = Flatten[
   Table[
    Graphics3D[{Point[{x, y, 0}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, bottomTileLength}, {0, bottomTileLength}, {0, 
        2}}], (*example*)
    {x, 1, topTileLength}, {y, 1, topTileLength}]
   , 1];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Okay so far so good. Now lets replace the example by real rectangles.
We doing this by defining our own function

`Rectangle3D[{xmin_,xmax_},{ymin_,ymax_},z_]:=Polygon[{{xmin,ymin,z},{xmax,ymin,z},{xmax,ymax,z},{xmin,ymax,z}}]`

The list for our Graphics3D has to be flattened and adding a table to construct our Rectangles.

```
Graphics3D[Flatten@{
   Table[Rectangle3D[{dx - 1, dx}, {dy - 1, dy}, 1.9], {dx, 1, 
     topTileLength}, {dy, 1, topTileLength}]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, bottomTileLength}, {0, bottomTileLength}, {0, 
    2}}]
```

Now lets add color for the specified condition, that we have an active field:

`... Table[{If[dx==x&&dy==y,Blue,Red],Rectangle3D[...`

[image]

We getting on our way. Now lets add the bottom layer and shift the top layer to the middle.

`...
midPointLength = (bottomTileLength - topTileLength)/2;
...
Table[{If[dx == x && dy == y, Blue, Gray], 
  Rectangle3D[{dx - 1 + midPointLength, 
    dx + midPointLength}, {dy + midPointLength - 1, 
    dy + midPointLength}, 1.9]}, {dx, 1, topTileLength}, {dy, 1, 
  topTileLength}],
Table[{If[False, Red, Gray], 
  Rectangle3D[{dx - 1, dx}, {dy - 1, dy}, 0.1]}, {dx, 1, 
  bottomTileLength}, {dy, 1, bottomTileLength}]
...`

The condition for the bottom layer is not that hard by also introducing a radius parameter for the convolution:

`...
If[
 x + midPointLength - radius <= dx <= x + midPointLength + radius && 
  y + midPointLength - radius <= dy <= y + midPointLength + radius,
 Red, Gray]
...`

[image]

Yeay, results.

Now finally add some Lines to the plot and afterwards make the colors a little bit more beautiful and add a little opacity as the final note:

**Full Code:**

```
Rectangle3D[{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, z_] := 
 Polygon[{{xmin, ymin, z}, {xmax, ymin, z}, {xmax, ymax, z}, {xmin, 
    ymax, z}}]
topTileLength = 5;
bottomTileLength = 9;
radius = 2;
midPointLength = Floor[(bottomTileLength - topTileLength)/2];
frames = Flatten[
   Table[
    Graphics3D[Flatten@{Opacity[0.8],
       Table[{If[dx == x && dy == y, Darker[Cyan], Lighter[Cyan]], 
         Rectangle3D[{dx - 1 + midPointLength, 
           dx + midPointLength}, {dy + midPointLength - 1, 
           dy + midPointLength}, 1.9]}, {dx, 1, topTileLength}, {dy, 
         1, topTileLength}],
       Table[{If[
          x + midPointLength - radius <= dx <= 
            x + midPointLength + radius && 
           y + midPointLength - radius <= dy <= 
            y + midPointLength + radius, Darker[Blue], Lighter[Blue]],
          Rectangle3D[{dx - 1, dx}, {dy - 1, dy}, 0.1]}, {dx, 1, 
         bottomTileLength}, {dy, 1, bottomTileLength}],
       Black, Thick, 
       Line[{{x - 1 + midPointLength, y - 1 + midPointLength, 
          1.9}, {x - 1 + midPointLength - radius, 
          y - 1 + midPointLength - radius, 0.1}}], 
       Line[{{x + midPointLength, y - 1 + midPointLength, 
          1.9}, {x + midPointLength + radius, 
          y - 1 + midPointLength - radius, 0.1}}], 
       Line[{{x + midPointLength, y + midPointLength, 
          1.9}, {x + midPointLength + radius, 
          y + midPointLength + radius, 0.1}}], 
       Line[{{x - 1 + midPointLength, y + midPointLength, 
          1.9}, {x - 1 + midPointLength - radius, 
          y + midPointLength + radius, 0.1}}]
       }, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, bottomTileLength}, {0, bottomTileLength}, {0, 
        2}}], 
    {x, 1, topTileLength}, {y, 1, topTileLength}]
   , 1];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, it helps a lot! It will take me some time to get through the code.

Comment: @Julien Kluge very cool. Yes, that's a good answer.